# Visualizing a 2D GSL matrix in SDL 2.0

Tags: c, image, sdl-2, grayscale, gsl

I have a 2D GSL matrix filled with real non-negative values.

Does anyone know an easy way to visualize that matrix as a grayscale image in SDL 2.0?

Comment: What problem are you having with your current approach?

Comment: @user694733: I found a function called `SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom` which I guess can be used for my purpose after setting its last 4 arguments to 0xFF0000. However, issues are that first my data is stored as a array of non-negative doubles inside the gsl matrix and I don't know how to pass that to the 1st argument of the above function. Second, how to set the depth and the pitch? (4th and 5th arguments)

Comment: I don't  think you can create surface directly from doubles. You need to convert those value to integers first. [Depth and pitch seem to be dependent on what pixel format you do the conversion to.](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot draw integers/doubles directly in SDL.
You need to convert them into characters first.
An easy way to do draw texts would be to use the SDL_ttf library to load True Type Fonts.
You have to load a font to render the string with.
Then create a rendered surface using the string and the font.
Then create a texture from the surface.
Finally render the texture and you'll have the .
Assuming you know the basics of SDL, the code goes like this

```
char* text = yourIntegerConvertedIntoCString;  
TTF_Font* font = TTF_OpenFont( path, ptsize );
SDL_Surface* surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font,  text, color );  
SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( renderer, surface );
SDL_FreeSurface( textSurface );
```

Then you render the texture normally as you do with other textures.
More [here](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_ttf)

Comment: I don't see why I need True Type Fonts to visualize a 2D matrix :s Do you mean that each value in the matrix would be mapped to a certain letter? I am really confused